# Migrate iPhone 3.1.3 app to iOS 4 compatibility (screen size and resolution)

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, migration

I've developed an iPhone 3.1.3 app and I want to make it compatible with iOS4.

Do I have to do something special?

iPhone 3GS screen is 480x320 px and 163 dpi.
iPhone 4   screen is 960x640 px and 326 dpi.

Do I have to change my images resolutions and views?

By the way, I've used iPhone 3 SDK. Now I'm going to install iPhone 4 SDK.

Comment: Here, I've found some explanation about that: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/6/29/updating-for-the-iphone-4-retinal-display.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything.  iOS will scale the images for you.

Comment: and, what about screen postions?

Comment: If you don't do anything special, it will just scale everything for you.